# Kubernetes Pod with Sleep command takes time to get deleted

Tags: kubernetes, sigterm

Currently it takes quite a long time before the pod can be terminated after a kubectl delete command. I have the feeling that it could be because of the sleep command.

How can I make the container stop faster?
What best practices should I use here?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: alpine
          ..
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
              trap : TERM INT 
              while true; do
                # some code to check something
                sleep 10
              done
```

Is my approach with "trap: TERM INT" correct? At the moment I don't see any positive effect...

When I terminate the pod it takes several seconds for the command to come back.

```
kubectl delete pod my-pod
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` to your spec will do:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10  # <-- default is 30, can go as low as 0 to send SIGTERM immediately.
      containers:
        - image: alpine
```